# libGDX - How to speed up scenario?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing an Android game, using libGDX in eclipse. I want to speed up my scenario (a treadmill) every time a player scores 10 points. The treadmill has an initial speed equals to 0, and recieves 5 for each 10 points. When the character fall out the screen, the player lose the game. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: There are a ton of ways to do this, and as it is your question is much too broad to answer. You're going to have to have a variable representing speed and increment it whenever appropriate. If you get stuck, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a specific question.

Comment: Before the question gets closed: multiply the deltaTime in your render() method by a certain value.

Comment: What I want to know is how can I accelerate the treadmill animation, specifically. And how do I bring my character with the treadmill animation, to fall out the screen? My treadmill and my character accelerate together, but in different ways, i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you realize the `treadmill` animation with `Animation`. First take a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation). You will note the `float stateTime` and the first parameter in `new Animation(0.025f, walkFrames);`. The `stateTime` describes your current time. This first parameter of `Animation` describes the duration of a frame. If `stateTime` is bigger then `frameDuration` the next `Texture`/`Sprite` of the `Animation` will be drawn.
You cannot change this `float frameDuration`, you can only set it in the constructor. But you can set the `stateTime`. Normaly you use `stateTime += delta`, so you have the exact time. To speed it up/ slow it down you can multiply it with `float speed`:

```
stateTime += delta * speed;
```

1. For `speed < 0` a frame would take longer, so the `Animation` is slower.
2. For `speed == 0` the `Animation` has its normal speed.
3. For `speed > 0` the `Animation` is faster.

If you die, just reset the `speed` to 0, so the `treadmill` won't be animated, as statetime never gets changed: `stateTime + (delta * 0) = stateTime`

Comment: At least add the right wiki and not the old one next time

Comment: Did not know that this is the old one. I was just looking for a tutorial and this one was looking good for me. So i posted this link. But thanks for the info :P Most times i find the old wiki first and the tutorials are almost the same

Comment: so you didnt see the big notice that they moved to Git at the top of the page you added...

Comment: Yea i knew, that they moved to Git. But i did not really look at the page where i am. I just was looking for a code sample, as i forgot how do you exactly create `Animation`s. I found this tutorial, looked at the code and well this was more or less the code i was looking for. I don't think that this is not working anymore, and there is a notification so everybody who is interested will also find the new wiki. But anyway thanks for editing it